# Assigning variable in for loop to the x coordinate of each point in an arraylist

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist, coordinates, variable-assignment

I'm trying to assign each x and y coordinate in my `ArrayList` to a variable as each coordinate will be compared to the coordinates of the point a user will click on the screen.

```
    // the coordinates of each point
    Point p1 = new Point(100, 100);
    Point p2 = new Point(100, 400);
    Point p3 = new Point(400, 100);
    Point p4 = new Point(400, 400);

    // the points are added to the arraylist
    mPoints.add(p1);
    mPoints.add(p2);
    mPoints.add(p3);
    mPoints.add(p4);
}
//this is the content of my arraylist

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {

      //motionevent detects motion from the user
      //float x;
      // x = event.getX();
      //float y;
      //y = event.getY();

      switch (event.getAction())
      {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //drawLine(x, y);
            //mContext = this.mContext;
            float Cox = event.getX();
            float Coy = event.getY();

            Double nearestDistance = 1000.12; //this is hardcoded for the sake of 
                                              //  declaring the variable.
            int NearestPoint =  -1;
            // int NearestPoint =  mPoints.get() ;
            for (int i = 0; i<mPoints.size(); i++)
            {
                float xi;
                float yi;
                xi = mPoints.x;
                yi = mPoints.y;
            }

//the assignments above are my problem
```

Comment: Specify what you mean with "compare". How would you like to compare them?

Comment: i will have a method that basically mimicks the Euclidean Distance formula. so the variables passed will be xi,yi,x,y (the coordinates of xi,yi will be the point the user clicks and the coordinates of x,y are of the point in the arraylist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, your for loop needs to look something like

```
for (int i = 0; i<mPoints.size(); i++)
{
    float xi = mPoints.get(i).x;
    float yi = mPoints.get(i).y;
    System.out.println("Point " + i + " y: " + yi);
    System.out.println("Point " + i + " x: " + xi);
}
```

This for loop will fetch each Point in the ArrayList and print it to the console. Instead of printing, you will want to call your method as needed.